# Finding process that deleted a file in git but didn't commit the delete

Tags: git

I am trying to track the process that has deleted a file in a git directory.
The git directory is in a shared place where all files are having u=rw,g=r,o=r and the owner is bot account say bot1.
This is a Linux environment.
Now in `git status` I can see fileA is deleted.
My question is not on the recovery, since weirdly enough this has happened twice now, I am trying to do a root cause on what is deleting this file. Or how it might be getting deleted.
To that end I want to know if there are any git commands to see more information about the unstaged change?

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    fileA
```

I have tried `git diff` and it didn't inform me on "how" the unstaged change was made.
It just informed what was changed.
I have tried reading the home ~/.*_history files to see if anything helpful is there but it seems they are overwritten.
I don't want to know how to recover the file. That is fairly simple.
I want to know if git has some utility to get some sort of metadata on how a tracked file got deleted.

Comment: This is more a linux / system administration question than a practical programming question. Consider asking on one of the linux sites instead, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: FWIW, git has no way of knowing _what_ modified the working tree. All git can do is look at the _current state_ of working tree when you run a `git` command.

Comment: It's Linux?  Use https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html to watch deletes and you should be able to log that info

Comment: Also, note that neither the permissions on the files nor the owner of the files matter. To delete a file, you only need write permission _on the directory_.

Comment: You say that the directory is shared. In which way is the directory shared? Are you using some cloud synchronization service?

Comment: @j6t this is an NFSv3 mount.

Comment: @Pi_die_die: is that NFS mount shared among several users ?

Comment: note that it is generally a bad idea to have a git repository (especially the internal `.git/` part) shared between several active users: if several users do git actions at the same time, you may get corruptions on the index, the branches state, get "race conditions" on what is to be committed (e.g: you run `git add && git commit`, but someone else executes a `git checkout other/branch && git add` between your two actions ...)

Comment: @LeGEC the permissions are configured to not be able do this but I get your point. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will not have that information with `git`.

`git` does not track how content was modified, it only inspects the content of a file at a given moment.

---

For what it's worth: your system doesn't track what processes altered a file either.

You will have to debug your issue through some other way.

For example: setting an inotify watcher can tell you *when* the deletion occurs, setting up an fanotify watcher can additionally tell you what process did it (or at least its pid).

Comment: This is what i suspected, that `git status` only looks at the current condition and is not globally tracking working tree activity constantly. I will setup inotify and fanotify as suggested thanks.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it. If you prefer, you are welcome to post an answer of your own, and accepting that. Accepting an answer helps future visitors by marking your problem as resolved. See also [help.](/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I misread the question. I'm leaving this up in case somebody else misreads it the same way; but basically any process other than `git` which somehow exposes the `unlink` system call could be the culprit here.

Some platforms offer filesystem-level hooks where you can get an alert whenever something is deleted; look at `iwatch` / `inotify` and friends.

Anyway, having a shared Git work directory definitely sounds dubious. Perhaps you want to avoid that. But this might simply be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

---

`git`, like most user commands, does not do anything like this. It simply executes whatever commands the user specified.

What you can do to troubleshoot this is to write a simple wrapper script which logs the user, current working directory, and command arguments before running the real `git`. Or, more drastically, replace the binary itself. Much more work, but much harder to bypass.

For the simpler solution, assuming your real `git` is in `/usr/bin/git`, you can shadow it with `/usr/local/bin/git` with contents like

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "[$(id):$(pwd)]: git $@" | logger
exec /usr/bin/git "$@"
```

If you already have your `git` in `/usr/local/bin`, a workaround is to rename it to `/usr/local/bin/git.really` and change the `exec` line in the script above to run that instead.

Some systems have OS-level audit logging which makes it easy to pull off this sort of thing without writing any wrappers etc; but then the burden of understanding, installing, maintaining, and monitoring those audit tools is a significant burden if you want to do it seriously. As an example, maybe look at [GNU `ac`.](https://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/accounting.html)

Ultimately, which user scheduled the removal of the file might not get you very far anyway. Perhaps you will need more context, like which parent process ran the command etc. The wrapper can capture this too if you can find or write a program to extract that information. (I have a gist in my Github called [`traceback`](https://gist.github.com/tripleee/0aea6984632c30956329) which attempts to do this on Linux when something returns an error.)

Comment: just to make something clear: the OP question boils down to "what process removed my file from disk ?". This action was *not* done using git or any of its subcommand: some other process ran `rm fileA` or renamed it or ... Logging what user ran a `git` action is probably irrelevant to the OP's issue.

Comment: The command seems to have been specifically `git rm` which not only removes the file, but also records the deletion in Git's staging area for committing. But I don't disagree that this seems like a wild goose chase.

Comment: the status posted by the OP says "changes not staged for commit" -- `git rm` would place it in the staging area

Comment: Ah, right you are - I definitely misread the question. In theory, you could put a similar wrapper around `rm`; but of course, it could be `perl -e 'unlink "fileA"'` or Python or Ruby or ...

Comment: As @LeGEC pointed out this deletion I am referring to a general deletion. Since any general deletion will be reported in `git status` as a deletion. If the deleting process is in fact `git rm` process then the steps you mentioned could help. But since I am more sure of the file that is deleted than the process, I will monitor the file deletion over time, than modifying regular commands with wrappers in a sort hit and trial way. There is some advantage to sharing a git folder in an nfs environment.

Comment: Oh, so the modifying process might not even be running on your computer? Ouch.